# Translate Oracle query to H2

Tags: sql, oracle, h2

I have the following query, which works fine in Oracle:

```
SELECT TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'MM') + LEVEL - 1 AS MYDATE FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE));
```

This query returns a list with all the days from current month.

The issue is that I need this query to also work in H2, but H2 does not support `LEVEL` or `TRUNC` or `CONNECT BY`. Therefore, how could I rewrite the query so that it works with both Oracle and H2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how could I rewrite the query so that it works with both Oracle and H2?

Not easily. Comparing Oracle and [H2 functions](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html):

- Oracle supports `TRUNC` and H2 supports `DATE_TRUNC`
- Oracle supports `LAST_DAY` and H2 does not.

H2 appears to support the functions `EXTRACT` and `CAST` and if it supports recursive queries then you could write something using only those functions (but it is not nice):

```sql
WITH days (day, month) AS (
  SELECT CURRENT_DATE
         - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) + 1
         - EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP)) / 24
         - EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) / 24 / 60
         - FLOOR(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) / 24 / 60 / 60,
         EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE)
  FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT day + 1,
         month
  FROM   days
  WHERE  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM day + 1) = month
)
SELECT day
FROM   days;
```

or, if H2 does not support adding numbers to dates then you can use `INTERVAL`s:

```sql
WITH days (day, month) AS (
  SELECT CURRENT_DATE
         - INTERVAL '1' DAY * (EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 1)
         - INTERVAL '1' HOUR * EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP))
         - INTERVAL '1' MINUTE * EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
         - INTERVAL '1' SECOND * FLOOR(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)),
         EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE)
  FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT day + INTERVAL '1' DAY,
         month
  FROM   days
  WHERE  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM day + INTERVAL '1' DAY) = month
)
SELECT day
FROM   days;
```

Which both output:

| DAY |
| --- |
| 2023-06-01 00:00:00 |
| 2023-06-02 00:00:00 |
| 2023-06-03 00:00:00 |
| ... |
| 2023-06-29 00:00:00 |
| 2023-06-30 00:00:00 |

I don't have access to a H2 instance to test whether it works on that RDBMS.

However, you may find it simpler to write different code for each database rather than trying to re-use the same code.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4J7rujW2)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query with both Oracle and H2:

```sql
WITH T(MYDATE) AS (
SELECT CAST(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE)
 - INTERVAL '1' DAY * (EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 1) AS DATE) MYDATE
FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(MYDATE AS DATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
FROM T
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CAST(MYDATE AS DATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY)
  = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE)
)
SELECT MYDATE FROM T;
```

But if you can use different queries, it will be better to use that one with H2:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(MONTH, CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY * X MYDATE
FROM SYSTEM_RANGE(0, EXTRACT(DAY FROM
  DATE_TRUNC(MONTH, CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '1' MONTH - INTERVAL '2' DAY));
```

(In future versions of H2 it will be possible to use a simpler query.)

Comment: In Oracle, a `DATE` has both date and time components and if you only subtract full days from `CURRENT_DATE` then it is still likely to have a non-midnight time component (unless you happen to run the query at midnight).

Comment: That's interesting, I thought that `CURRENT_DATE` in Oracle returns a `DATE` without time part, but actually it actually returns a value with both date and time parts.

Comment: I added the `TRUNC` function to my query, it should fix this problem. Datetime version of this function is deprecated in H2, but it still works.

Comment: I thought that the OP's issue was (partly) that H2 doesn't support `TRUNC` for dates (only numbers) and you would need to use `DATE_TRUNC` in H2 instead?

Comment: H2 doesn't support additional arguments in `TRUNC()`, and H2 2.1.214 doesn't support `LAST_DAY()` (H2 2.2 will support `LAST_DAY()`).